# Qt: display an image (QLabel) inside a QScrollArea

Tags: c++, image, qt, qlabel, qscrollarea

I am trying to display an image inside a `QScrollArea` located on the `QMainWindow`.

[image: GUI]

I want a fixed size for the image display, and scroll bars to appear if the loaded image is bigger than the `QScrollArea`. My problem is that when I load an image which is bigger than the `QScrollArea`, the image appears cut (which is ok) but no scroll bars appear on the UI.

Taking into account various recommandations from other stackoverflow questions, here is the generated code from the Qt designer:

```
mImageScrollArea = new QScrollArea(centralWidget);
mImageScrollArea->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mImageScrollArea"));
mImageScrollArea->setGeometry(QRect(440, 0, 400, 700));
mImageScrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget();
scrollAreaWidgetContents->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"));
scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 398, 698));
mLabel = new QLabel(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
mLabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mLabel"));
mLabel->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 700));
QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(mLabel->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
mLabel->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
mLabel->setScaledContents(true);
mImageScrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
```

When an image is loaded, I display it in the label as follow:

```
QPixmap wPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(mImage);


ui.mLabel->resize(wPixmap.size());
ui.mLabel->setPixmap(wPixmap);

ui.mLabel->show();
```

Why aren't any scrollbars showing if the image I load is bigger than the QScrollArea ?

Comment: Maybe you need to resize the `scrollAreaWidgetContents` too? Scroll bars appearance depends on the size of containing widget.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you provide UI file content instead of generated C++ code. Anyway, it seems that `scrollAreaWidgetContents` doesn't have a layout. You need to add a grid layout to it in Qt Designer. After you do this, you will not need to resize label or `scrollAreaWidgetContents` manually. They will be resized automatically. Calling `show` on label is not required either, it will be visible by default (unless you have hid it).